# Hibernate default schema and Table annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, schema, spring-data

I am using `Spring Boot 1.3.5` and `Hibernate 5.1`. Property that tells Hibernate what the schema to work with is called is

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema
```

The value (schema name, lets say *development*), however, Somehow it does not get picked-up when creating tables with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`. Only way to get it work (at least what works for my case) is that each entity class has schema name defined with

```
 @Table(name = "some_table", schema = "development")
```

---

It would be great if tables could be created in the schema defined in **spring boot application properties** (possibility to be passed as ENV for different environments). If schema is not specified in `@Table` annotation the table is created in public schema.

Is there a way to set schema for tables without setting it in the Table annotation but with property file config only?

Comment: I have same usecase where we need to use different schemas. Did you find workaround for this?

Comment: Same issue here, I use postgresql

Comment: @roberttrudel see solution that works for me in the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a year now app evolved and I am using `Spring Boot 1.5.4` and `Hibernate 5.1.5` with `Postgres 9.6`. Not sure if there were issues with previous versions but now it works fine.

`yaml` configuration file:

```
spring:
   datasource:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      platform: postgresql
   jpa:
      properties:
         hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
            default_schema: SCHEMA_NAME
```

Although using 9.6, [PostgreSQL94Dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL94Dialect.java) can be used for 9.4 and later as there is no specific PostgreSQL96Dialect for given Hibernate version.

With this there is no need to specify schema in `@Table` annotation.

**Update October 2018**

See Hibernate's repository for supported dialects and set git tag to your Hibernate version: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect

Comment: It's org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect now

Answer (score 1):

you can add this configuration if you use hibernate session factory;

```
@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}")
private String HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingLocations(HIBERNATE_HBM_RESOURCES);

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a cleaner solution with property file only.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. But along with the schema also add

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

to your properties file.

Comment: Hi, please explain the purpose of this config.